# jsf output text with fn substring

Tags: jsf, output, formatdatetime

I want to format a date in jsf which is xmlgregoriancalendar type. I've come across post which say I need custom converter. Does anybody found solution which does not require custom date converter. I was trying following but I gives me error saying...

**Element type "h:outputText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".**

This is what I tried on jsf

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:substringBefore(aClip.lastTransmittedDate,"T")}">
     <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

Can anybody point out the explain the error I'm getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from your EL syntax error (basically, with that nested double quote you're ending the attribute value too soon that it becomes `value="#{fn:substringBefore(aClip.lastTransmittedDate,"` which is completely wrong EL syntax), this is after all absolutely not the right approach.

The `<f:convertDateTime>` converts `Date` to `String` and vice versa. It does not convert `String` in date pattern X to `String` in date pattern Y at all as you incorrectly seemed to expect.

Given a `XMLGregorianCalendar`, you need [`XMLGregorianCalendar#toGregorianCalendar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar%28%29) to get a concrete [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance out of it which in turn offers a [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) method to get a concrete [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instance out of it, ready for direct usage in `<f:convertDateTime>`.

Provided that your environment supports EL 2.2, this should do:

```
<h:outputText value="#{aClip.lastTransmittedDate.toGregorianCalendar().time}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

Or, if your environment doesn't support EL 2.2, then change the model in such way that you have for example a getter returning `java.util.Calendar`:

```
public Calendar getLastTransmittedDateAsCalendar() {
    return lastTransmittedDate.toGregorianCalendar();
}
```

so that you can use

```
<h:outputText value="#{aClip.lastTransmittedDateAsCalendar.time}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

You can even add a getter returning the concrete `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this error points that you have not well-formed XML. In EL you should use single quotes to indicate `String`. In your case `value="#{fn:substringBefore(aClip.lastTransmittedDate,'T')}"`

What about date converter, you should see on the type of `#{aClip.lastTransmittedDate}` property.
If it is date, just use

```
<h:outputText value="#{aClip.lastTransmittedDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

If it is not date (i.e. String), `<f:convertDateTime/>` won't work, and you should reformat it in Java code. For example, create another getter that will return modified string representing property value.